# How can I install the SDK tools offline after just installing Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just downloaded Android Studio and after installing it asked to download the SDK tools. I downloaded all the zip files which were required to be installed(not from SDK manager). But now I want to know that how to install all these packages?(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXail.png)

This is how the SDK folder look like after I extracted the initial basic packages. And I have installed Android Studio and after that just extracted these packages in the SDK folder and I didn't extracted anything. When I try to make a new project it shows add on list. So tell me what should I do?

Comment: You don't "install" them. Just extract and copy the packages in the Android SDK location on disk

Comment: Still it is showing no SDK found. It is asking me to download the same components again but I have extracted the zip files already. Now what should I do?

Comment: Can you please edit the question to show the folder content? Also is that folder exported as your `ANDROID_HOME` or `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must configure SDK correct path in your android studio setting... provide correct path

Comment: When I try to configure the path with internet it starts downloading the emulator, platform tools,etc again. And when I do it without internet it shows Android is up to date. But the path doesn't changes and add on list shows again.